# How do I customize my current code such that it will show the specific usage for each Course ID in my query

Tags: ms-access

[This is my SMS TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyaoe.png)

[This is my Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnkM6.png)

[This is the code used for SMS USAGE]

```
SMS USAGE: DSum("[SMS COST PER MESSAGE]","[SMS TABLE]","[COURSE ID] = 'C0001'")
```

How do change current code such that it reflects the criteria for all of the course ID for all the different rows.

Eg. Rows 1-3 has the same course ID C0001 therefore SMS Usage is reflected correctly.

Rows 4-6 have the same Course ID C0002 therefore the code criteria should be `[COURSE ID] = 'C0002'"`
so on and forth

How can I make the code more fluid or at least allow me to change the code for each specific row?
Also is it possible to change the SMS Usage format to currency? $ sign and 2 decimal places

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Reference the [Course ID] field by concatenation to use it as a dynamic parameter.

`SMS USAGE: DSum("[SMS COST PER MESSAGE]","[SMS TABLE]","[COURSE ID] = '" & [COURSE ID] & "'")`

However, domain aggregate functions can perform slowly in query and textbox. Did you try an aggregate (GROUP BY) query? Another issue with the DSum() is that if you filter the records, that will not be considered in the DSum() unless you included the same filter criteria in the DSum(). So say you filtered for a particular date range, the DSUM() will return values for the entire table.

Could build a report and use its Grouping & Sorting feature with aggregate calcs, this allows display of raw data as well as summary calcs.

Advise no spaces or punctuation/special characters (underscore only exception) in names. Also, all caps not advised, harder to read. Better would be CourseID or Course_ID.

Comment: Sorry I tried it but I'm not sure how it works exactly and therefore wasnt able to integrate it.      As my Course ID appears in multiple tables as primary and secondary keys,an error popped up for the code:The specified field could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL statement.

Comment: Edit your question to provide the SQL statement of the attempted query. Still advise DSum() is not the best approach.

Comment: Is it possible for me to give you a link to the access file?Basically my final goal is to calculate SMS cost for all the different Course ID and compile the fields I need to create a mailmerge and send it to all the Staff members.

Comment: By SQL do you mean like this? 
SELECT SUM(SMS COST PER MESSAGE) AS 'Total', [COURSE ID]
FROM SMS TABLE 
GROUP BY [COURSE ID]

Comment: Spaces in names so need to use [ ]. `SELECT SUM([SMS COST PER MESSAGE]) AS 'Total', [COURSE ID] FROM [SMS TABLE] GROUP BY [COURSE ID];`. A mail merge with Word? An Access report won't serve instead? You can post link to file.

Comment: Sorry for troubling you, here is the link https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bzg_k-wSQL6VbVp3MUh2cTRrWVU 
The purpose of the mailmerge is to remind the staff of the specific course of the current sms usage and the allowance.

Comment: Did you try the modified query? If you use the query designer, it should handle the bracketing for you. So how did you get SQL without [ ]? Ooops, copy/paste bit me. Instead of 'Total' I should have changed to [Total].